# Struck at custom resource registration-K8s

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I was trying to deploy [prometheus-kubernetes](https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes). After I ran `./deploy`,

```
Deploying Prometheus Operator
serviceaccount "prometheus-operator" configured
clusterrole "prometheus-operator" configured
clusterrolebinding "prometheus-operator" configured
service "prometheus-operator" configured
deployment "prometheus-operator" configured
Waiting for Operator to register custom resource definitions..............^C
```

Then I looked into the `deploy` and try to run `kctl get customresourcedefinitions servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com`.

```
ubuntu@test-box:~/prometheus-kubernetes$ kctl get customresourcedefinitions servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com
kubectl get customresourcedefinitions servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com
Error from server (NotFound): customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com" not found
```

My `kubectl version`,deployed on AWS instance.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.2", GitCommit:"bdaeafa71f6c7c04636251031f93464384d54963", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-24T19:48:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.2", GitCommit:"bdaeafa71f6c7c04636251031f93464384d54963", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-24T19:38:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```