# How to monitor network i/o of pods with Azure Monitor for containers

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have deployed a few apps in Azure Kubernetes Service(AKS) and I need to monitor CPU usage, memory consumption, and network io(received bytes, sent bytes) of each deployed app.

I was able to find CPU and memory usage stats in the `Perf` table (log analytics workspace) with counter names `cpuUsageNanoCores` and `memoryWorkingSetBytes` respectively. So that I was able to monitor each pod's resource consumption.

However, I am unable to find any network stat belongs to pods in AKS even though azure agents are recording those metrics as documented in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/OMS-docker/blob/vishwa/june19agentrel/docs/InsightsMetrics.md#host-network-metrics).
Furthermore, I can see network metrics for k8s nodes (only for nodes) are available in `InsightsMetrics` table.

What I want to know is, does the Azure log analytics provides network monitoring at the Pod level? If so are there any documents that I can refer to to retrieve those network metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Azure Network Policy Manager aka NPM to monitor your network. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/kubernetes-network-policies#monitor-and-visualize-network-configurations-with-azure-npm) is a link to the documentation.

For more pod metrics, you may check [cAdvisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952058/k8s-monitoring-with-prometheus-pod-metrics?rq=1) or [dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/technology-support/cloud-platforms/microsoft-azure-services/supporting-services/monitor-azure-kubernetes-service/)